# Preventing IMG from Resizing and Inconsistent Div Height Change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Currently I have a huge div that would collapse from the height it automatically generated to the height of the title of the div. (i.e. 32px). I have it start out collapsed and then when I click on the div it opens to its full size, displaying all its inner information, and then when I click again, it collapses again. Unfortunately, two things happen:

1. The div doesn't completely expand to its full height.
2. The first large img in the div gets resized.

Now I understand why the latter is happening. It has something to do with the height being a percentage instead of a discrete number, for when I change the number to something like 500px, it works just fine. But I don't want to do that. I *need* it to remain a percentage for when I need to use, yet resize, large pictures.

I also feel this same problem may coincide with the former problem as well, but I'm not sure.

Please help me with this.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is the title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="example"> <span class="h2">DIV Example</span>

        <br />
        <img class="big" src="http://www.greenbookblog.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/big-data.jpg" />
        <p>This is a big picture. It's here to show what this thing is supposed to be doing.
 However, this picture has been squished so that it can fit within the div nicely. I am
 writing a bit so that I can take up space.</p>
        <img class="big" src="http://www.greenbookblog.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/big-data.jpg" />
        <p>This is a big picture. It's here to show what this thing is supposed to be doing. However, this picture has been squished so that it can fit within the div nicely. I am writing a bit so that I can take up space.</p>
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 div.example, div.example img {
      border: 3px solid #402468;
      border-radius: 6px;
  }
  div.example {
      color: white;
      margin: 0 15px;
      background-color: #504689;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  img.big {
      width: 85%;
      height: 85%;
  }
  /*further formatting: pay no mind*/
  div p {
      text-indent: 15pt;
      margin: 0 15px;
  }
  .h2 {
      font: 32px"Times New Roman", serif;
      color: #678900;
  }
```

aaaand jQuery:

```
 $(document).one("ready", function () {
     $("div.example").each(function () {
         $(this).data("height0", $(this).height());
         $(this).height("32px");
     });
 });
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("div.example").click(function () {
         if ($(this).height() !== 32) {
             $(this).animate({
                 height: '32px'
             });
         } else {
             $(this).animate({
                 height: $(this).data("height0")
             });
         }
     });
 });
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/AirStyle/rb95K/35/

Also this is what I get:
https://jsfiddle.net/AirStyle/rb95K/35/embedded/result/

CAUTION: I may not have made the percentages small enough for the picture used. Please lessen them if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the height setting altogether and it will keep aspect ratio

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/8hj00Lky/))

```
img.big {
    width: 85%;
}
```

Also you should cache your jQuery objects. I've done this in the demo by caching `$(this)` to `var self = $(this)` and then referring to self therein. There is a lot of overhead in initializing jQuery objects, so if you're using the same selector more than once, cache it.

#### Edit:

Because you are setting the height of the div to a fixed height on expansion, if the user resizes the window the images will grow in width as well as height. As the container is a fixed height the contents will grow past the end of the container and get cut off. If you would like to fix that, add a "complete" function to the animation to remove the height setting and make it dynamic again.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/7jgef13s/1/))

```
self.animate({
    height: self.data("height0")
},function() {
    self.height('');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not sure why it was doing either one of my problems...can you expound on that? I don't think I was able to garner my answer from your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add `height: auto;` to maintain the default aspect ratio.

```
img.big {
    width: 85%;
    height: auto;
}
```